# How to fix overlap in table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents

I have problem with table of contents. Here is my script on LATEX.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[top=2cm,left=3cm,bottom=2cm,right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[bahasa]{babel}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{tocbasic}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pagecolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,breaklines=true}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Teorema}[section]
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definisi}
\newtheorem{result}[theorem]{Hasil}
\AtBeginDocument{
    \let\mtcontentsname\contentsname\renewcommand\contentsname{\MakeUppercase\mtcontentsname}
}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\center\bfseries}{\large\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}~\thechapter}{0.5cm}{\large}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{1cm}{-1cm}{1cm}
\titleformat{\section}[hang]
{\bfseries}
{\bfseries\thesection}{1ex}{\bfseries}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
linefill=\bfseries\TOCLineLeaderFill,beforeskip=2pt,entrynumberformat=\chapterprefixintoc,dynnumwidth
]{tocline}{chapter}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\normalfont\bfseries}
\newcommand*\chapterprefixintoc[1]{\MakeUppercase{\chaptername}~#1\enskip}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\begin{document}
    \onehalfspacing
    \frontmatter
    \input{cover.tex}
    \cleardoublepage
    \input{katapengantar.tex}
    \newpage\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{DAFTAR ISI}
    \tableofcontents
    \mainmatter
    \input{pembahasan.tex}
    \input{daftarpustaka.tex}
\end{document}
```

And this is the output of my tbale of contents.
[image]

This is script for `\input{cover.tex}`

```
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
2019
\end{center}
```

This is script for `\input{katapengantar.tex}`

```
\chapter{KATA PENGANTAR}
```

This is script for `\input{pembahasan.tex}`

```
\chapter{PEMBAHASAN}
\section{Pendahuluan}
\section{Metode Shooting}
\subsection{Metode Bagi Dua/Bisection}
\subsection{Solusi Masalah Nilai Batas}
```

This is script for `\input{daftarpustaka.tex}`

```
\def\bibname{DAFTAR PUSTAKA}
\def\refname{DAFTAR PUSTAKA}
\begin{thebibliography}{65}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{DAFTAR PUSTAKA}
\end{thebibliography}
```

Why is the word "PEMBAHASAN" overlap with word chapter "BAB I"? What is the problem? Thank you.

Comment: Did you run the code at least three times? Option `dynnumwidth` needs an additional run.

Comment: Yes, I've done it, but still overlap. Usually it works, but I dunno why this time it doesn't work.

Comment: Using your code I can not reproduce the issue. Why do you load package `titletoc`? It is not recommended to use more than one package regarding the TOC and the Lists.

Comment: I've solved the problem. The script isn't not error, but it is my tex studio. When I run the script on my friend's tex studio it had no problem at all.